# Node Js CreateWriteStream will not write to directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, fs

I can not seem to make fs.createFileStream write to a directoy.

```
var filePath = fs.createWriteStream('./path/to/store/file.png');            
var rem = rquest('http://domain.com/img/img.png');

rem.on('data', function(chunk) {
    filePath.write(chunk);
    response.write(chunk);
});

rem.on('response', function(res){
    response.writeHead(200, res.headers);
});

rem.on('end', function() {
    response.end();
});
```

It works fine if I i jsut pass a file name into CreateWritStream

```
var filePath = fs.createWriteStream('file.png');
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: It will not create the directories on its own. All the directories in the path should exist and should be writable.

Comment: That makes total sense, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as stated by @thefourtheye in the comments section

> It will not create the directories on its own. All the directories in the path should exist and should be writable.

was the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

Strangely, I was experimenting with uploading files to Apollo server on Codesandbox and when specify folders created graphically (create new folder context menu) it throws error, but with folders created with mkdir from terminal everything is working perfectly ;)